# How do I use rusqlite's Row::get method for a type which I don't know at compile time?

Tags: sql, rust

I am using Rust's `rusqlite` crate to insert and recall data from a sqlite database.

I am using the `get()` method for its [`Row`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.17.0/rusqlite/struct.Row.html) that returns a `Result<T>`. I have this current code snippet:

```
while let Some(row) = rows.next()? {
    let value = match row.get(0).expect("Could not get value from database cell.") {
      // Do something here to specify types and return them or add them to a separate collection
   };
}
```

How could I specify the type? Currently the only way I can properly unwrap the `get` function is by assigning it to a variable with a specific type already, like `let value: i64 = row.get(0).unwrap()`, but I don't know how to differentiate if the `get(0)` was actually a string or a boolean or any other acceptable SQL type.

I've searched through other examples of `match` with `Result`, but their match enums are based off values, not types.

Comment: You can use enum as the result type and put the necessary payload into the enum variant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How could I specify the type? Currently the only way I can properly unwrap the get function is by assigning it to a variable with a specific type already, like `let value: i64 = row.get(0).unwrap()`

If I understand what you want correctly, you're looking for [`get_raw`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.21.0/rusqlite/struct.Row.html#method.get_raw) and [`get_raw_checked`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.21.0/rusqlite/struct.Row.html#method.get_raw_checked) which return [a `ValueRef` enum](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.21.0/rusqlite/types/enum.ValueRef.html) this way you can check at runtime what type the retrieved value was:

```rust
while let Some(row) = rows.next()? {
   let value = match row.get_raw(0) {
         ValueRef::Null => ...
         ValueRef::Integer(i) => ...
         ValueRef::Real(f) => ...
         ValueRef::Text(t) => ...
         ValueRef::Blob(b) => ...
   }
}
```

`get` indicates an expectation and returns an `Err` if the expectation is betrayed, because usually you know what the type of the value stored in the column *should* be, and if someone went under you and replaced the column or value's type, then everything is broken. It also conveniently handles [various conversions](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.21.0/rusqlite/types/trait.FromSql.html) so you don't have to handle them by hand.

Incidentally if you don't want to handle the possible error from `get` you can just use its sibling [`get_unwrap`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.21.0/rusqlite/struct.Row.html#method.get_unwrap).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `T` on your `Result<T>` is coming from the table scheme, so `T`'s type will be already determined by the database, not by Rust.

Usually a good practice is to create a `struct` that maps your SQL table like in the [example on the documentation](https://docs.rs/crate/rusqlite/0.21.0).

SQLite side

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name            TEXT NOT NULL,
    time_created    TEXT NOT NULL,
    data            BLOB
)
```

Rust side

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
    time_created: Timespec,
    data: Option<Vec<u8>>,
}
```